# SQL Query to include 3rd colum in WHERE Exist CLAUSE

Tags: sql

How can i include the `SUM(tonnage_adjusted)` of a column in `DeliverTons` into this sql query to produce my 3 column of values needed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CROP_CLASS As Opened,SUM(ACREAGE) AS SumofAcreage
From CaneParcel
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DeliveryTons WHERE CaneParcel.FIELD_ID = DeliveryTons.parcel_id AND parcel_status = 1) 
Group By CROP_CLASS
Order By SumofAcreage DESC
```

Comment: Convert your query to `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: @ivias - It depends on what kind of relationship the two tables have. You should provide some sample data and expected result to clarify what you're after

Comment: Mixing SELECT DISTINCT and GROUP BY is only for experienced users...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will solve your problem

```
SELECT  
CROP_CLASS As Opened,
SUM(ACREAGE) AS SumofAcreage,
SUM(tonnage_adjusted) AS TonnageAdjusted
FROM 
CaneParcel
INNER JOIN DeliveryTons ON CaneParcel.FIELD_ID = DeliveryTons.parcel_id AND parcel_status = 1
Group By CROP_CLASS
Order By SumofAcreage
```

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here.

Comment: Hi how can i also get the acreage included in the sum when parcel_status is also 2 and 3. I added : AND parcel_status = 2 and just this change made the query take longer to execute and brought in a huge number. Bascially i woul want to also take into consideration of the 2 previous statuses and SUM them.

Comment: Change parcel_status = 1 to parcel_status in (1,2,3)